# MVC routes with special characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to support some legacy urls, and map them to controller actions.  The URLs look like this:

```
/~Home+Office~Note+Pads.html
```

Here's my route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "LegacyCategory",
    "{path}.html",
    new { controller = "LegacyCI", action = "Index", }
);
```

Here's the (beginnings of) my controller to deal with them:

```
public class LegacyCIController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index(string path) {
        if (path == "~Address+Labels") {
            return RedirectToAction("Display", "Category", new { id = "AddressLabels" });
        }       
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Category"); 
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint in LegacyCIController, and I set my start page to XXX.html, the breakpoint hits (and fails the `if`) and life is good.  But when I try to set the start page to `~Address+Labels.html`, no breakpoint is hit, and Chrome just pukes and shows me a page that says "oops, this page appears to be broken".

I'm running this page through IIS 7 on my machine, not Visual Studio.

Is this URL so malformed that a regular MVC route can't even handle it, or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty jacked file name.

Comment: @Tejs - yes, yes it is.  Dealing with legacy stuff is one of the true joys of life :)

Comment: My theory is that IIS is bouncing the request - I think IIS7 has a blacklisted URL character set.

Comment: @Tejs - that's what I was afraid of.  IIS tinkering is not my specialty.

Comment: Try setting up some kind of logging to see what is going on. For example implement custom error handling and if error occurs send it to yourself with an email.

Comment: Do you have IIS 7 Request Filtering On? DenyUrlSequences would most likely have to be configured then

Comment: Have a look at double escaping option: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/143/use-request-filtering/ I believe by default IIS7 blocks the `+` character.

Comment: @ShawnC. - can you expand that into an answer so I can upvote?  That looks like it's on the right track

Comment: @pjumble - based on your article, it looks like what I need is to turn this request filtering **off**

Comment: You should just need to turn on `allowDoubleEscaping`, in the `system.webServer` section of `web.config` try putting `<security><requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"></requestFiltering></security>`

Comment: @pjumble - good god - that worked.  Thank you!  Please post that as an answer so I can get you all sorts of glorious rep :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default IIS7 blocks URLs (error 404.11) with a `+` in the path, you can override this by turning on [`allowDoubleEscaping`](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/143/use-request-filtering/) in `web.config`:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

However, as explained on the IIS blog this option opens a potential security hole, so be a little careful while using it:

http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2007/12/17/iis7-rejecting-urls-containing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HandleUnknownAction`.  In your controller:

```
protected override void HandleUnknownAction( string actionName ) {
  if( Request.Path == "/~Address+Labels.html" ) {
    RedirectToAction( "Display", "Category" ).ExecuteResult( ControllerContext );
  } else {
    base.HandleUnknownAction( actionName );
  }
}
```